# how to receive nonenglish character as spring bean

Tags: java, html, spring, tamil

In my project i am getting the nonenglish character from form.If a get a form parameters as @RequestParam.It display the nonenglish character.If i get the form parameter as bean it displays some unwanted character.

```
<form action="selva" method="get">
<input type="text" name="s" value="அன்பு" />
<input type="submit" value="fgf"/>
</form>
It displays:அன்பு
<form:form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="multipleSave" modelAttribute="multipleSave">
    <input type="text" name="userName" value="அன்பு"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form:form>
It prints : à®¤à®¿à®²à®à®µà®¤à®¿
```

How to resolve this error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Do you have `CharacterEncodingFilter` configured in your application?

Comment: no,i am not configuring CharacterEncodingFilter

Comment: Probably this is the problem. Could you please add `CharacterEncodingFilter` to your filter chain with UTF-8 encoding. Also it would be helpful to see code example for right and wrong cases

Comment: thanks @Oleksii Duzhyi after adding the filter  <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter> my code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing `org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter`. You can add it either via web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

or via Spring java configuration file:

```
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        ....
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = servletContext.addFilter("characterEncodingFilter", characterEncodingFilter);
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
        .....
    }
}
```